# How to extract value type from object and keys in typescript

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

I am using `arg` and `fp-ts`. I want to have a function that returns type based on one of the inputs key value.

```js
export const getArg =  <T extends Spec> (args: Result<T>) => (argName: {[K in keyof T]: T[K]}): O.Option<T[K]> =>
    O.fromNullable(args[argName])
```

But it says that I can't index with `K in keyof T`, despite `K` being the actual keys. And it won't see `K` in `Option`. I need some help with types.

`Result`

```js
    export type Result<T extends Spec> = { _: string[] } & {
        [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends Handler
            ? ReturnType<T[K]>
            : T[K] extends [Handler]
            ? Array<ReturnType<T[K][0]>>
            : never;
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't make it work with `arg` library. But I was able to extract type with `command-line-args`

```js
export const getArg =
  (args: CommandLineOptions) =>
  <K extends keyof CommandLineOptions>(
    argName: K
  ): O.Option<CommandLineOptions[K]> =>
    O.fromNullable(args[argName])
```

The right way to it was to use `extends keyof` instead of `in keyof`, and then reference the desired type via `F[K]`